# Sencha Chart 2.0 - Multiple Selection

Tags: selection, bar-chart, sencha-charts

I am looking the way to manage multiple selection on a Bar Chart. Is it possible?

Actually, I am using this configuration:

```
interactions: [
....
'itemhighlight',
...],
series: [
                {
                    type: 'bar',
                    highlight: true,
                    ....
                }
            ]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, how is possible to detect "select" event?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on Sencha Chart Forum:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?226314-Multiple-Selection-Bar-Chart&p=844157